# HQL one to many relationship?

Tags: hibernate, hql

In my application i have `@OneToMany` Hibernate relationship as follow

```
public class Lot {

    @OneToMany (cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    private List<ProductAvailable> productAvailable;

}

public class ProductAvailable {

    private String productName;
    private double netAmount;

}
```

Question: I want to retrieve a list of `Lot` objects in which each `Lot` object must have sum of `netAmount` of all of the corresponding `ProductAvailable` objects ?

What should be the HQL query to retrieve expected list of Lots ?

Answer (score 0):

Just a suggestion, it would be easy if you use groovy objects for your entity classes. Groovy closures provide easy solutions to such questions and saves number of lines of code.

If Lot and ProductAvailable are groovy objects then

```
public double getTotalAmount(){
    return productAvailable.sum { it.getNetAmount() }
}
```

Calling this method on Lot instance would give you the sum of netAmount of all the products available in that lot. Saves you from writing HQL queries too

Comment: Thank you @Mrunal but i am not familiar with groovy at all !